# Toolbox components used in .Net framework with visual c++

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, desktop-application

I am building an desktop application in visual c++.
I have a question about the toolbox components like buttons, textbox, date time picker, data grid view, etc. I want to use latest windows 10 UI but in my case, UI seems pretty much old like windows XP or vista.
[Search button and Date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHtgz.png)
[Data grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L1ba.png)

I have installed latest version of SDK and .net framework, also I have checked the solution properties which shows that I am using windows 10 SDK latest version and .net framework v4.8.1 but the buttons, textbox, date Time picker, etc. are of very old version.
[Solution properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcsOu.png)
[.Net framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvD4o.png)

Please help me with this. I shall be grateful

I am expecting UI to be look like this :
[Data grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2zCm.png)
[Textbox and Search button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnYjz.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How did you create the C++CLI Winform? Can you provide steps to create the project and  add controls? The CLR  .NetFramework template does not reproduce your problem.